# Get values from checkboxes Ruby on Rails, Many to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, many-to-many

I'm trying to get the values from some checkboxes in a form. The form:

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>


<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'user_ids[]', user.id,false -%>
  <%= h user.name -%>
  <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Save" %>

<% end %>
```

The book `has_and_belongs_to_many` users, so what I want to do is to add the `user ids` from the checkboxes to `@book.users`. How can I do that? I keep getting error: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_ids.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model add this line and try out

```
attr_accessor :user_ids
```